# SQL Loader not able to load file

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, sql-loader

While trying to use SQL Loader, it keeps showing

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 1.
Expecting keyword LOAD, found "?".
LOAD data infile 'DataCenterData.csv' into table temporal
```

I want to understand why is telling me that is expecting a LOAD keyword, while that's exactly what I have at the beginning of in my .ctl file, or at least, understand what's the meaning of the "?" symbol.

PD: this is what I'm using to load the data

```
sqlldr ****/****@ORCL18 control=control.ctl, DATA=DataCenterData.csv skip=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a BOM (Byte Order Mark). I just saved the file again but with the correct encoding.